# File System metaphor

Tags: t-sql, filesystems

I'm wondering how to rapresent the file system metaphor (ntfs is based on btree right?) inside a SQL database.
Obviously data are stored as rows into tables and don't use the NTFS storing method; so, how NTFS (and other FS) logically works to rapresent the files/folders hierachy?
Any advice or references?

Thanks for the support.

Comment: In short; probably don't! Use the file system!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: There is one reason to do it: Transactions

Comment: @dmeister : Sure. But I don't see that requirement in the poster's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have some kind of database, stored in DBMS, simply build the table with the following fields:

- ID
- Parent ID
- Name
- Type (directory or file)
- Modification date (creation date and last access date are optional)
- Data (BLOB)

and that's it. ID/ParentID would let you build a hierarchy, and the rest is details.

Most filesystems have inverted structure of ID/ChildrenIDList instead of ID/ParentID but this is caused by specifics of filesystem design. If the filesystem is backed by some relational DBMS, then having a parent ID might be more optimal for lookup.